# RegisterWaitForSingleObject undefined behavior with ManualResetEvent

Tags: c#, multithreading

In one of my projects, I need to schedule a task to be done after some specified interval in the background thread. I use the `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject` mechanism to do that.
According to the documentation, the first argument could be a `WaitHandle` which has many sub classes. At first I preferred `ManualResetEvent`; I use this event to signal to fulfill the schedule and exit. Here is my code:

```
public class ScheduleTester
{
    private long m_LastTicks;
    private RegisteredWaitHandle m_RegisterWaitHandle;
    public ManualResetEvent Event;

    public ScheduleTester()
    {
        Event = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        m_RegisterWaitHandle = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(Event, new WaitOrTimerCallback(WaitOrTimerCallback), null, 500, false);
        m_LastTicks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    }

    private void WaitOrTimerCallback(object state, bool timedOut)
    {
        long ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

        if (timedOut)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Timeout : {0} ... Do scheduled job takes 1 seconds long, Thread ID : {1}", (ticks - m_LastTicks) / 10000f, Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode()));                                
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Signaled....Unregister , Thread ID : {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode()));

            if (null != m_RegisterWaitHandle)
                m_RegisterWaitHandle.Unregister(null);
        }

        m_LastTicks = ticks;
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    ScheduleTester waitFor = new ScheduleTester();
    Console.ReadKey();
    waitFor.Event.Set();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

What I expected is to see many lines which notify a scheduled job has done until I press a key to signal the event and a single line noticed the scheduled fulfilled. 
But what I see is:
[image: output1]

When the `ManualResetEvent` is replaced with `AutoResetEvent` every thing is good.
[image: output2]

Comment: Maybe just delete all of this and replace with `Task.Delay`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because if event stays signalled - `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` will execute callback again and again. You have to reset event to stop that, which is done automatically by `AutoResetEvent` (hence it's name). The reason you don't have infinite number of "Signaled" messages is because you `Unregister` your wait handle, which stops `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` timer.

Comment: I understand the mechanism, which is confused me is that i `Unregistere` it at the first call! but calling the callback continues, and the count of it is unpredictable, with many try, different calls showed up.

Comment: That is because between the moment event is signaled and moment when you call Unregister - already a lot of delegates are dispatched to thread pool, that is why they all get executed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is not exactly very intuitive behavior.  You can easily see the underlying problem from the debugger's Debug > Windows > Threads window.  You'll see a large number of tp threads all executing your WaitOrTimerCallback() method.

It is up to you to stop this from happening.  The `executeOnlyOnce` parameter of RWFSO is very, very important.  You now pass `false`, that makes it important that the sync object you wait for gets signaled only once.  Like AutoResetEvent does.

If you use a ManualResetEvent then you *must* pass true.  And tweak your callback to:

```
private void WaitOrTimerCallback(object state, bool timedOut) {
    long ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    if (timedOut) {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Timeout : {0} ... Do scheduled job takes 1 seconds long, Thread ID : {1}", (ticks - m_LastTicks) / 10000f, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
        ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(Event, new WaitOrTimerCallback(WaitOrTimerCallback), null, 500, true);
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Signaled....Unregister , Thread ID : {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
        m_RegisterWaitHandle.Unregister(null);
    }
    m_LastTicks = ticks;
}
```

You'll now see it detecting timeouts at the wait interval.  Not sure if that was intended.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, when i changed the code to do some work takes many seconds long( with `Thread.Sleep`),  The callback raised at its timeout , so whether the `WaitHandle` signaled or the timeout passed the callback raised,

Comment: Well, that's what happens when the timeout you specify is too short.  You need to think about what you need to do when you detect a timeout.  Console.WriteLine() does not quite cut it.  There is no single correct answer but you'd consider, say, something like CancellationTokenSource.Cancel() to tell the worker thread to stop.